# Facebook Fan Page feed on Website (Age-Protected)

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

Need help in trying to get posts/wall posts from a fan page that is age-gated on facebook to show up on my site.

the fan page is age gated to only let those 17 and over to view it (when they are logged into facebook). But, my website is behind an age gate (locally), so I want to show the posts from that facebook page on my site.

I've seen it done before, but I was never able to look at the person's code to see how he/she did it and I can't locate anyone who has tried or successfully pulled it off.

I've created an app on facebook, tied to my account, that is able to see any page on facebook (whether it's age gated or not):

Here is my code

```
    <?php

function fetchUrl($url){

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

 $feedData = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch); 

 return $feedData;

}

$profile_id = "(Page id)";

//App Info, needed for Auth
$app_id = "123456789";
$app_secret = "123456789abcdefghij";

$authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");

$json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/posts?{$authToken}");




$feedarray = json_decode($json_object);

echo $json_object;

foreach ( $feedarray->data as $feed_data )
{
    echo "<h2>{$feed_data->name}</h2><br />";
    echo "{$feed_data->message}<br /><br />";
}

  ?>
```

The code works for pages that do not have an age gate, but those that do, it returns as invalid (the JSON cannot process anything since the $authToken is returning nothing).

anyone want to help me figure this out?

Comment: It looks like you are using app access token. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the pages that are accessed with the **App Access token** are restricted to retrieve data from public Facebook pages, the one anyone can open without logging in.
But for the particular case here, the Posts you want to pull, are from an **Age Gated** Page. So Facebook requires you to log-in (if you aren't already) so that it can decide to show or not the Page.
The same is also [documented](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) as :

> To read a Page you need:
>
> 1. an app or user access token for public and non-demographically restricted pages
> 2. a user access_token for restricted pages that the current user is able to view (no special permissions required)

So you need to utilize **User Access Token** to access the page so that Facebook may allow your application access to Page's Posts.

Comment: How do I go about getting that done in my code? I don't have any facebook login/user login on my site.

Comment: Would there be an issue in doing the same? Also keep a note of the [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) that states `You must not circumvent (or claim to circumvent) our intended limitations on core Facebook features and functionality.`

Comment: What issue are you speaking to?

Comment: @Keoki .. The issue of showing an Age Gated page's Posts to people who aren't able to see it, i.e Age Gated to see it.

Comment: Since my site is behind an age gate, I don't see an issue.

Comment: @Keoki .. Well then this solves any possible problem on breach of platform policy. Have you got success in accessing the Posts from the Age Gate page using the User Access token ? Do tell if you still got any issue.

Comment: I don't know where to start with getting a USER access token since I don't have a login on my site (don't need it) and from what I'm reading, it requires a user to accept an application before the User access token can be generated. I have a user account (the one used to create the application) that is able to view age-protected page, so how can I get that account's user access token, then use it for my site?

Comment: Simple and fast way would be using [explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to get normal access token after selecting your application in list of applications. Then you can [extend](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/) the token and use it further for next 60 days to access the data from Facebook Pages

Comment: thanks, I've tested through the Explorer: generated USer access token and used FQL query to pull the page posts. How can I translate that to my current code?

Comment: @Keoki Just set the value of your `$authToken` as the value you have got and the rest would work without any issue. Also just as a security pointer,please keep the token a simple User access token without any extra permissions. Just a User access token is enough to access the Posts

Comment: thanks. what happens when the 60 days expire (for the extended access token). do i have to renew it every time it does?

Comment: Yes @Keoki, you will have to do that, this is one restriction with the token duration. You can retrieve it same as you have obtained it now

Comment: So, in order for me to be able to see POSTS from an Age-Restricted Fan Page on a Website, I need an User Access Token from - let's say - a user who is administrator for that page? Also, do we want a 'simple' User Access Token or the one with the extended permissions (manage_pages, read_stream)? I've tried several Tokens (including what I think is a Page Token) but I can't see any content from the page in my website (unless I remove the age restrictions).

Comment: @Edd Yes to view the POSTS from age restricted page, you would require a User Access Token, even a normal User Access Token will do what is required. A simple user access token is required for the same.

Comment: My question was if I could use the admin's access token instead of having the webpage visitors logging in to Facebook (and then use their access token). I could not do this.

Comment: Yes you can use the admin's token, it will be non-expiring token and can be used for your use.